# I am running into "error: expected expression before ‘Matrix’ " in C and can't figure out what is wrong

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am trying to add the Matrix*partiklar into my update_boids function so that I can use the values that I have saved in a struct earlier in the main function. I am bashing my head against this error as I can’t understand where it’s coming from. Could you please help me understand how to solve this?

I am quite new to C and am using gcc with the SDL library installed on my machine for the graphics.

I get this compiler error:

`main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:123:20: error: expected expression before ‘Matrix’
make: *** [main] Error 1`

Which points to these lines of code:

```
update_boids(Matrix *partiklar);
```

With Matrix defined as follows:

```
typedef struct Matrix
{
  double MatX;
  double MatY;   
  double MatZ; 
} Matrix;
```

And partiklar like:

```
Matrix partiklar[NR_BIRDS];   
Matrix hastighet[NR_BIRDS];   
Matrix *p[NR_BIRDS];   
Matrix *v[NR_BIRDS]; 
int t = 0;
   while(t<NR_BIRDS)   
{     
partiklar[t].MatX = rand()%100;     
partiklar[t].MatY = rand()%100;     
partiklar[t].MatZ = rand()%100;     
p[t] = &partiklar[t]; 

hastighet[t].MatX = rand()%10;     
hastighet[t].MatY = rand()%10;     
hastighet[t].MatZ = rand()%10;     
v[t] = &hastighet[t];      

/*printf("%f\n", partiklar[t].MatX);     
printf("%f\n", partiklar[t].MatY);     
printf("%f\n", partiklar[t].MatZ);    */
t++;   
}
```

Comment: error is in `main()`, show the main function

Comment: Where is the return type of `update_boids(Matrix *partiklar);`?

Comment: `update_boids(partiklar);`

Comment: Thanks for the help! I declared partiklar wrong (as you said) and should have left the Matrix* out of the update_boids to start with.

Answer (score 1):

The line the error points to looks like a function prototype with an implicit return type of int.  If it is a function CALL, then you need to leave off the type (the compiler already knows it from wherever partiklar was declared).

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the input! (I keep running into syntax errors that are just stupid...)